# new dict record from string in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have strings list, and want to compare each string in list a number of its entrance. I try it by this code:

```
words = dict()
for str in lst:
    words[str] += 1
```

Whan I run it, I have error with the output:

```
KeyError: 'in'
```

What is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Words` is an empty dictionary. No matter what `str` (a very bad variable name btw) would be you will get a `KeyError`.

You may want to take a look at [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)